# NullPointerException - passing parameters from one controller to another the accepting controller does not accept the passed parameter, SQLConnection

Tags: controller, parameter-passing, javafx-8

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Projects/Java/TinyTool-2.4/out/production/TinyTool/views/list/ListDepartments.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2606)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2576)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2446)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2414)
    at tinytool.controllers.detail.ControllerUserInfo.showDepartmentList(ControllerUserInfo.java:526)
    at tinytool.controllers.detail.ControllerUserInfo.departmentList(ControllerUserInfo.java:163)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3473)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3401)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3769)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3488)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1765)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2497)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:411)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:941)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoopImpl(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoop(WinApplication.java:214)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.enterNestedEventLoop(Application.java:515)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.EventLoop.enter(EventLoop.java:107)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(QuantumToolkit.java:634)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.showAndWait(Stage.java:478)
    at tinytool.utilities.Switcher.showUserInfoScreen(Switcher.java:67)
    at tinytool.controllers.ControllerMainScreen.menuUserInfo(ControllerMainScreen.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1405)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$6(ContextMenuContent.java:1358)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3760)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3488)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1765)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2497)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:411)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:941)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:185)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2571)
    ... 105 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at tinytool.database.server.DAO_Departments.getDepartmentList(DAO_Departments.java:36)
    at tinytool.controllers.list.ControllerListDepartments.initialize(ControllerListDepartments.java:55)
    ... 115 more
org.mariadb.jdbc.Connection@2315b05
```

The connection is active and connected to the MariaDB server 
This is the method in the **calling** class that will display a list of valid records

```
private void showDepartmentList() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(TinyTool.class.getResource("/views/list/ListDepartments.fxml"));
        AnchorPane pane = loader.load();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.setTitle("Departments/Areas");
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image(tinyTool.ICON + "department.png"));
        stage.setWidth(400);
        stage.setHeight(360);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        ControllerListDepartments controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setServerConnection(serverConnection, localUserRecord);
        stage.showAndWait();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(serverConnection);
    }
}
```

The "serverConnection" as in the output is connected to the MariaDB

This is the controller that is being called by the above method, but here the
serverConnection for some reason is **null** or not accepted by the public method
*setServerConnection*

```
public class ControllerListDepartments {
    private final DAO_Departments daoDepartments = new DAO_Departments();
    private final Utilities utilities = new Utilities();
    private LocalUserRecord record = new LocalUserRecord();
    private Connection serverConnection;
  
    @FXML private TableView<DepartmentList> tblDepartments;
    @FXML private TableColumn<DepartmentList, String> colName;
    @FXML private TableColumn<DepartmentList, String> colCode;
    @FXML private JFXTextField txtSearch;
    @FXML private Button btnSelect;
    @FXML private Button btnClose;
  
    @FXML void initialize() {
        colName.prefWidthProperty().bind(tblDepartments.widthProperty().multiply(0.1));
        colName.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().deptNameProperty());
        colCode.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().deptCodeProperty());
        
        ObservableList<DepartmentList> departmentList = 
daoDepartments.getDepartmentList(serverConnection, true);
    }

    public void setServerConnection(Connection connection, LocalUserRecord userRecord) {
        this.record = userRecord;
        this.serverConnection = connection;
        userRecord.setDepartment(record.getDepartment());
    }
}
```

This is the DAO in the error is reported by *getDepartmentList* and the connection parameter

```
public class DAO_Departments {
    public ObservableList<DepartmentList> getDepartmentList(Connection connection, boolean active) {
        String sql;
        
        if (active) {
            sql = "SELECT * FROM tinytool.departments WHERE dept_status = 1 ORDER BY dept_name;";
        } else {
            sql = "SELECT * FROM tinytool.departments ORDER BY dept_name;";
        }
  
        try {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            ObservableList<DepartmentList> departmentList = createDepartmentList(resultSet);
            statement.close();
            resultSet.close();
            return departmentList;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity"
            prefHeight="360.0" prefWidth="400.0"
            xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            fx:controller="tinytool.controllers.list.ControllerListDepartments">
    <JFXTextField fx:id="txtSearch" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="321.0" promptText="department name" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" />
    <ButtonBar layoutX="186.0" layoutY="305.0" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0">
        <buttons>
            <Button fx:id="btnSelect" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Select" />
            <Button fx:id="btnClose" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
        </buttons>
    </ButtonBar>
    <TableView fx:id="tblDepartments" layoutX="-41.0" layoutY="-8.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="60.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="colName" editable="false" maxWidth="400.0" minWidth="400.0" prefWidth="400.0" text="Department/Area" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="colCode" prefWidth="75.0" text="C2" />
        </columns>
    </TableView>
</AnchorPane>
```

I am missing something seriously stupid and I have no idea what that is. Looking at the code over-and-over is somehow not solving the problem. If someone could point me to what I am NOT seeing I would be greatful.